# MemTest86 errors when RAM is in dual-channel and CPU is multi-threaded

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, bsod

I have an [Intel NUC DC33217CK](http://ark.intel.com/products/68308/Intel-NUC-Board-D33217CK) PC that has been in my possession for the past few years. Lately, it has been getting GSODs (green screen of death - the BSOD equivalent for people on the Windows 10 Insider Preview) at an annoying rate so I thought about refreshing Windows but, before I went through with that, I decided to run MemTest86 first.

I've had GSODs before but it rarely appeared. I have two sticks of Kingston 99U5469-046.A00LF 1333MHz 4GB RAM installed in the NUC for a dual-channel total of 8GB and I've been suspecting at least one of them may be faulty.

The first run of MemTest86 alarmingly threw hundreds of errors after the default four passes and I was initially convinced that I have a RAM problem. But, after taking each one of the sticks individually through MemTest86 and them trying them in each of the two slots without errors, I was only left confused. I'm now typing this on the actual PC but with just one module installed. No GSODs so far.

I then thought that maybe I have a RAM timing problem so I played around with manually and painstakingly adjusting the timings in the BIOS. I found a setting that seem to minimize the number of errors to a certain degree but, nevertheless, the errors remained. Also, I was getting the best experience when running the modules with 1.35V instead of the rated 1.5V.

Then, for some reason, I thought about changing some CPU settings. I reverted the RAM settings to default then I first switched off HyperThreading. Errors again. I then switched the number of cores from ALL to 1. No more errors. WTF?!

I also tried switching HT on again. Hello errors, though it wasn't as bad as when all cores are running.

So, in summary I get MemTest86 errors when running RAM in dual-channel mode when more than 1 CPU thread is enabled. I can run the system with no errors when:

- I use only one RAM module (any one of them) or...
- I use only one core.

I chose to go for the former. Having just one core is too limiting. However, 4GB RAM is, more or less, still usable. I just have to cut down on my multitasking.

So the question is... what could be my problem then? Is my NUC motherboard faulty? Could it be my CPU or could I fix this by buying some new RAM?

I'm thinking of testing different RAM modules hoping to run them in single-channel mode just to see if the results are the same. I'll need to borrow some first though. I'll just update the question once I get another module.

**Update 1:**
I'm rather sad that no one has yet to enlighten me. However, I do have a legitimate update about the issue. I was able to borrow another 4GB module but it's a 1600MHz module from another manufacturer. I actually wanted a module with different specifications so that I could ensure that dual-channel will not be enabled and, lo and behold, no errors.

So this confirms my suspicion that dual-channel is the culprit but I have yet to confirm what the actual problem is. Hopefully, I can find someone to lend me a pair of RAM for testing dual-channel with a different set of modules or maybe use my modules on their machine to see if there are any differences.

Comment: Any memtest failures at all would tell me that the RAM is suspect.  I would rule out the motherboard by getting a replacement set of RAM sticks and trying them in the same configurations that caused the first set to fail.  Not certain how to differentiate motherboard / CPU problems in the NUC, is that CPU removable?

Comment: "I'm rather sad that no one has yet to enlighten me." - We don't know the answer to your question, or specifically, the person that does know the answer, has not seen your question.  The fact different hardware worked indicates you just ran into a memory compatibility problem.  If I say this question 3 days ago, I would have suggested that, which turns out to have solved your problem.

Comment: @Cristopher Hostage, unfortunately, the CPU isn't removable so trying the RAM modules on another computer or a different set of RAM would be the only option. I'm still trying to find a way to test those scenarios without spending any money by borrowing a computer or RAM modules from people I know. Hopefully, I can do that soon.

Comment: @Ramhound, I meant that sentence like an expression. Nothing more. I apologize if it sounded like I was disappointed or something. The problem is rather unusual so I did expect that it may take time to get actual answers. I may even end up answering it myself. Though I have found a way around the problem, it is still basically, unsolved. My curiosity can get the better of me and I really want to understand why this is happening and how to fix it, if even possible. This would be for the benefit of other people who may encounter the same issue in the future and end up on this post, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find someone who has a dual-channel set of compatible RAM that I can lend from but I did get a chance to use a laptop that is compatible with mine. And, after a quick test, there were no errors. So my modules are working correctly. This leaves us with the motherboard or CPU. Sadly, isolating them cannot be done because the CPU is soldered to the board.

My bet is on the CPU as modern CPUs tend to have the memory controller in the CPU die. I think that the system controlling dual-channel RAM may be faulty. Might also be some sort of voltage issues in the controller so, maybe, trying DDR3L RAM could make dual-channel work. That's just a conjecture with no basis, though. I might try doing that when I have extra money to spend. Or I may just purchase a module that is different to my current model so that I can, at least, have more RAM to spare. Either way, I've (kinda) solved my problem so I'll leave it at that.